# How to extend ProductSlider AbstractCmsElementResolver

Tags: shopware6

I've seen two ways to decorate a product slider resolver with additional information and now I don't know which procedure is correct. Both lead to the result. But which way is the right one - especially with regard to compatibility with other extensions that also start at this point.

**Plugin XYZ:**

```
<service id="PluginXYZ\Content\XYZProductSliderCmsElementResolver">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolver"/>
    <tag name="shopware.cms.data_resolver"/>
</service>
```

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PluginXYZ\Content;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolver;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\Aggregate\CmsSlot\CmsSlotEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\Element\AbstractCmsElementResolver;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\Element\ElementDataCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\ResolverContext\ResolverContext;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\CriteriaCollection;

class XYZProductSliderCmsElementResolver extends AbstractCmsElementResolver
{
    /** @var ProductSliderCmsElementResolver $elementResolver */
    private $elementResolver;

    public function __construct(ProductSliderCmsElementResolver $elementResolver)
    {
        $this->elementResolver = $elementResolver;
    }
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->elementResolver->getType();
    }
    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        // Some Changes
    }
    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $this->elementResolver->enrich($slot, $resolverContext, $result);
    }
}
```

**Plugin ABC:**

```
<service id="PluginABC\Content\ABCProductSliderCmsElementResolver" decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolver">
    <argument type="service" id="PluginABC\Content\Product\Cms\ABCProductSliderCmsElementResolver.inner"/>
    <tag name="shopware.cms.data_resolver"/>
</service>
```

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PluginABC\Content;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\Aggregate\CmsSlot\CmsSlotEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\Element\AbstractCmsElementResolver;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\Element\CmsElementResolverInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\Element\ElementDataCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\ResolverContext\ResolverContext;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\DataResolver\CriteriaCollection;

class ABCProductSliderCmsElementResolver extends AbstractCmsElementResolver
{
    /** @var CmsElementResolverInterface $elementResolver */
    private $elementResolver;

    public function __construct(CmsElementResolverInterface $elementResolver)
    {
        $this->elementResolver = $elementResolver;
    }
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->elementResolver->getType();
    }
    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        // Some Changes
    }
    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $this->elementResolver->enrich($slot, $resolverContext, $result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing the resolver for exclusive use with your own custom element, which should build on the existing resolver, then you may inject the element resolver like you did in the first example. In that case your element should also be referable to by it's own unique type. Multiple resolvers per type are not an alternative to the actual decorator pattern. In case you do plan to implement it for a custom element though, be sure to hint to the interface of the injected service instead, in case other plugins actually do decorate the service.

```php
public function __construct(CmsElementResolverInterface $elementResolver)
{
    $this->elementResolver = $elementResolver;
}

public function getType(): string
{
    return 'my-custom-slider';
}
```

The decorator pattern, on the other hand, is the right approach if you want to enrich the data for all usages of the product slider element. Just make sure to always call the methods of the decorated service.

```php
class ABCProductSliderCmsElementResolver extends AbstractCmsElementResolver
{
    private CmsElementResolverInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(CmsElementResolverInterface $elementResolver)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->decorated->getType();
    }

    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        return $this->decorated->collect($slot, $resolverContext);
    }

    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $this->decorated->enrich($slot, $resolverContext, $result);
    }
}
```

In short, the question which implementation is preferable depends on the scope your extension should have. Enriching all instances of an existing element, or just those of a new custom element.